# Javascript to grab Javascript (more) comments within <head>

Tags: javascript

I originally received help in this thread: [Javascript to grab Javascript comments within <head>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305706/javascript-to-grab-javascript-comments-within-head).

Where I wanted to use Greasemonkey/Javascript to grab a comment from within  tags.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <!-- 12036,2011-11-29/11:02 -->
    <title>Products & Services</title>
```

The answer I received in the thread above grabbed the number "12036" and displayed this as an overlay on my page. Now I want to grab the second part (the date) ie "2011-11-29" and also display this as an overlay.

What do I need to add/change from the following to grab the date?

```
var commentNode = [].slice.call(document.head.childNodes).filter(function(node) {
        return node.nodeType == 8;
      })[0],
id = commentNode.data.match(/^\s*(\d+)/)[1];

var elem = document`.createElement('div');
elem.id = 'id-display';

elem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(id));

document.body.appendChild(elem);
```

Comment: You just need to change the regular expression, to match everything between the comma and the space. Isn't that obvious?

Comment: Sure, and what would that regular expression be?

Comment: I don't understand what's happening. I'm not a programmer and never claimed to be. I need basic programming help with this regular expression.

Comment: If you're not a programmer, why are you programming?

Comment: @Barmar: long story. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I just hope you're not going to be posting here every day, asking us to write your application for you. This site is not supposed to be a substitute for doing your own work, it's for help when you run into roadblocks.

Comment: Noted. Thanks for helping me with this roadblock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `id = ...` line with:

```
id = commentNode.data.match(/,(.*?)\s/)[1];
```

Go to regular-expressions.info to learn about regular expressions.